# open web browser using lua in a vlc extension

Tags: lua, vlc

I am writing a VLC extension in which i would like to open some url in a web browser( in lua of course ). So far, I have not been able to find any relevant code for opening the web browser from a lua script. Is there any way in which I can perform this task (say for example a google search of the file playing)?

I am able to create a link to the url using a dialog box, but i would like to skip this step and make it open without any user input.

I am a beginner to lua and to making VLC extentions( just started a few days back ) and have been trying things out since then.

Comment: any browser(preferably the system default). i just need to open a url..

Comment: It depends on the operative system. I'm guessing you would have to a) detect the operative system host and b) execute an os-specific command via the command line. You might be able to do b) with the os.* lua package, if it's available for vlc extensions. I have no idea how to do a) from vlc though.

Comment: thanks kikito :) I'm working on windows, and i just used os.execute("start http://www.google.com") and it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact command varies between operating systems:

- On Windows:
  `start http://example.com/`
- On *nix (most portable option):
  `xdg-open "http://example.com/"`
- On OSX:
  `open http://example.com/`

---

The following Lua sample should work on Windows, Linux, and OSX (Though I cannot test OSX).
It works by first checking Lua's `package.config` for the `\\` directory separator (which, afaik, is only used on windows). That should only leave us with OSes that support `uname`. Then I take a flying leap and assume that Mac will identify as 'Darwin', and thus anything that doesn't is *nix.

Obviously, this is somewhat less than exhaustive.

```
-- Attempts to open a given URL in the system default browser, regardless of Operating System.
local open_cmd -- this needs to stay outside the function, or it'll re-sniff every time...
function open_url(url)
    if not open_cmd then
        if package.config:sub(1,1) == '\\' then -- windows
            open_cmd = function(url)
                -- Should work on anything since (and including) win'95
                os.execute(string.format('start "%s"', url))
            end
        -- the only systems left should understand uname...
        elseif (io.popen("uname -s"):read'*a') == "Darwin" then -- OSX/Darwin ? (I can not test.)
            open_cmd = function(url)
                -- I cannot test, but this should work on modern Macs.
                os.execute(string.format('open "%s"', url))
            end
        else -- that ought to only leave Linux
            open_cmd = function(url)
                -- should work on X-based distros.
                os.execute(string.format('xdg-open "%s"', url))
            end
        end
    end

    open_cmd(url)
end
```